# Action bar Icon menu issue on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar

well just when I solved an issue another one is comming right there, and I don't know if I'm violating any rule of this forum posting everything I got an issue, I hope not, but here I go again, I'm trying to add an Icon menu to the Action bar within my fragment, on my parent activity I don't know have action bar menu, so I don't trying to replace the menu on my fragment, because I just use a DrawerLayout to drawer a list menu and it's all, but in some specific Fragments I want to show some action bar icon menu, I've search in the forum before posting but I didn't find something than can help me, because I'm not sure what is going on, I did the two stepts to show and action bar menu on fragments read on others post, I even tried using the default menu.xml created by android studio, in two differents fragment, but for some reason the menu is not being showing on fragments Action bar, I'm not sure if I have to do something on my parent Activity first, but here are my both code Activity and Fragmen

Parent Activity code which is declared the DrawerLayout menu list

```
import java.util.ArrayList
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String[] titulos;
private DrawerLayout NavDrawerLayout;
private ListView NavList;
private ArrayList<Item_objct> NavItms;
private TypedArray NavIcons;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
Fragment ventas;
NavigationAdapter NavAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__main);

    NavDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);

    NavList.addHeaderView(header);

    NavIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_iconos);

    titulos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_options);

    NavItms = new ArrayList<Item_objct>();

    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[0], NavIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));

    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[1], NavIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[2], NavIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));

    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[3], NavIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[4], NavIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));

    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[5], NavIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


    NavAdapter= new NavigationAdapter(this,NavItms);
    NavList.setAdapter(NavAdapter);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            NavDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* Icono de navegacion*/
            R.string.app_name,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.hello_world  /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            Log.e("Cerrado completo", "!!");
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Log.e("Apertura completa", "!!");
        }
    };


    NavDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    NavList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            MostrarFragment(position);
        }
    });


     ventas = new VentasFragment();

}

private void MostrarFragment(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            //fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = ventas;
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new customerFragment();
            break;
        default:
            //si no esta la opcion mostrara un toast y nos mandara a Home
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Opcion "+titulos[position-1]+"no disponible!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // fragment = new HomeFragment();
            position=1;
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();


        NavList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        NavList.setSelection(position);

        if(position > 0)
            setTitle(titulos[position-1]);
        else
            setTitle("Balance General");

        NavDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(NavList);
    } else {

        Log.e("Error  ", "MostrarFragment"+position);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        Log.e("mDrawerToggle pushed", "x");
        return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Fragment Code where I want to implement the action bar menu

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class customerFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static customerFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    customerFragment fragment = new customerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
public customerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        //mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

As you see on Fragment Code, I call setHasOptionMenu(true); whithin onCreat() in the last line, and I inflate my menu.xml whithin onCreateOptionMenu(), but I doesn't showing anything anyways, I'm not pretty sure about what is going on, why It doesn't work anyways.

Thank you so much beforehand, and sorry if the issue is quickly obvious, I'm beginner yet and I don't understand a lot of things of Methods Overriding and Callings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try to add items programmatically instead of `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)`, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.add(0, R.id.your_id, 0,
            getResources().getString(R.string.your_string))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

That's working for me.

Comment: Perfectly @Romadja, I got this to work with you example, Thank you so much, anyways, It's a kind of weird why It's doesn't work when i Inflate my resource menu .xml File, if anyone see the error, please notice this, I really want to understand why exactly it doesn't work. Thank you so much to everyone for the comments

Comment: Exactly, its working... And please help me to include actionLayout to the menu, dynamically... (Like a search layout )